# Testing that OptaPlanner constraint generates match weight for a specific score level

Tags: unit-testing, optaplanner

I have unit tests that use the following testing API:

```
constraintVerifier.verifyThat(myConstraint).given(myEntity).penalizesBy(someValue);
```

But, I would like to be able to also verify it is penalising / rewarding as a Hard, Medium or Soft score. Is there a way to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no. You can not do that on a constraint level, but you can do that [on a `ConstraintProvider` level](https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/constraint-streams/constraint-streams.html#constraintStreamsTestingAllConstraints).

Comment: The reason the API asserts the `matchWeight`, but ignores the `constraintWeight` is because constraintWeights are often volatile, especially as an implementation hits production and the stakeholders debate about the constraints, often negotiating about the constraint weights. By isolating the constraint unit tests from the impact of those discussions, it is **much easier to alter the constraint weights to today's business needs**, without having to refactor a large portion of unit tests.

Comment: That being said, if you can write down a good motivation why you should have the option to also assert the constraint weights, we can accept an RFE to add API methods for that.

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet In our case the users get to manage their own constraint weights, but not the score level (hard, medium, soft), so am happy with that methodology. What I am looking for is the ability to test specific constraints but ensuring that the score level is as expected. It is not a deal breaker, it would just be a nice to have.

Comment: I'd use a validation on the `@ConstraintConfiguration` class, to validate that all the `@ConstraintWeight` fields are their expected weight level.